# php PDO query doesn't work with hash_hmac()

Tags: php, hash, pdo, sha

I just read about hash_hmac() function,
i tried to use it for storing password in DB :

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test';
$username = 'root';
$pass = 'password';

$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, TRUE);

$password = '123MonyeTSahuR456';

    $p = addslashes(hash_hmac('sha256', $password, '13#slP3mK;"dA$@m', TRUE));    

    $query = "INSERT INTO table_one VALUES(NULL, :password)";

try
{
    $pdo = $conn->prepare($query);
    $pdo->bindValue(':password', $p);

    if($pdo->execute())
    {
        echo $pdo->rowCount();
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'fail';    
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**the DB details:**

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT
password VARBINARY(32) NOT NULL
```

after that i manually check my DB and found a row with BLOB(i never work/use with VARBINARY or BLOB data type before, so this is my first time)

so there's 1 row exist and i try to select the row :

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE password = :password";
```

the value returned by `pdo->rowCount()` is 0 , it doesn't find the password im looking for, anyone can tell me why? how to fix this?

**another details :**

PHP version : 5.4

OS : Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit
thanks

Comment: repeat the test but instead of `$pdo->bindValue(':password', $p);` use `$pdo->bindValue(':password', '12345');`

Comment: Are you looking for the literal password after you stored its hash previously? Why is there an `addslashes`?

Comment: did you try to use `$pdo->bindValue(':password', $p, PDO::PARAM_LOB);` also?

Comment: Burn that book. You are using prepared statements. There's no need for extra escaping. In particular not totally silly escaping functions like addslashes, which are not meant for database context.

Comment: @mario actually its my fault because the book's using mysqli.. so yeah guys, thanks for your help and tips. And why if i use PDO::PARAM_LOB it works(at the time i use addslashes()) ? i know it unneccessary to use PDO::PARAM_LOB and addslashes instead of just remove the addslashes, but im just curious

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

by using **PDO::PARAM_LOB** in the query, it works..

1 more thing in my mind is :

- should i use `addslashes()` before the query? i just follow the tutorial for the `addslashes()` thing